# autologin on 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I have just installed 19.04. I have tried to set autologin ON with the toggle in account settings. It will automatically reset to OFF after leavinfg account settings display box.
I have also tried to achieve the same thing with editing 'custom.conf' in /etc/gdm3/. This does not work either! What am I doing wrong.

Comment: auto login does not work with an encrypted disk.

Comment: Disk is not encrypted !